# HierarchyRequestError in sp.ui.rte.js

Tags: javascript, error

How can I resolve this error?  I see this in Firebug's Javascript Console for `sp.ui.rte.js` on every Sharepoint Page that's loaded.  It persists through an `iisreset`.  And it is always the very last thing that happens in page load.

> HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point
>   in the hierarchy
>   ...egenerate-skip")};RTE.RteUtility.$DK=function(a,b){ULSNVe:;a.push("");a.push...

How can I trace this error?

[I found this page which suggests and answer](http://www.johnchapman.net/technology/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-javascript-errors-sp-ui-rte-js-sp-ui-rte-debug-js/#comment-3285), but I'm not sure if it is the same problem.  But I've tried several of these `FixRTEBug` attempts, all to no avail.

**[update]**

After testing various pages, I have concluded that the error only happens in wiki pages.  It does not happen on webpart pages containing Content Editors.  Wiki Home Pages, Wiki Libraries, etc.

In the console, the last call before this error is a `GET` statement for

```
https://my.portal.org/helpdesk/_layouts/commandui.ashx?ver=-780422973&id=Ribbon.ListForm.Edit&lcid=1033&qt=ribbonvisibletabdeep
```

**[update before my bounty expires]**

Here is a screenshot of IE's debugger:

[image: IE's Debugger]

Does anyone have *any* clue at all?  My bounty is going to expire...

Comment: My bounty is almost over.  I don't want it to go to waste, so I'm going to award it even if I don't solve my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Judging from what the console is saying, it seems that the method `RTE.Canvas.checkCurrentFocus` fails because the element passed is `null` and the method doesn't expect it to be, so you get an error when it tries to call `null.parentElement` since parentElement is not a valid property of the object.

Searching on Google it seems to be a issue several others are also having with SP 2010:

https://www.google.com/#q=RTE.Canvas.checkCurrentFocus

Their fix seems to be overwriting the method. Not the ideal solution but if you too are on SP 2010 then that might be the solution to your issue as well.

I don't have the source files in front of me, but maybe this napkin code gets you on the path to fixing the issue:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.ui.rte.js', null, function() {
    var backup = RTE.Canvas.checkCurrentFocus;
    RTE.Canvas.checkCurrentFocus = function(a) {
        if (a !== null) {
            return backup.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
});
```

> Edit: adding a followup to the comments below.
>
> If `SP.SOD.executeFunc` isn't available when your code runs, either
>   because it loads too quickly, or if it loads but the error already
>   occurs because the method was used before the hotfix was applied, try
>   running this code right after `sp.ui.rte.js` is loaded. Preferably if
>   the master file allows for it, load yours right after it loads with
>   the following script:
>
> ```
> (function() {
>   var backup = RTE.Canvas.checkCurrentFocus;
>   RTE.Canvas.checkCurrentFocus = function(a) {
>       if (a !== null) {
>           return backup.apply(this, arguments);
>       }
>   };
> })();
> ```
>
> Alternatively if loading after is too late, and loading before will of
>   course not work, we could do something like this to wait for it to
>   load so we inject our code as soon it is available. Note that this is
>   not the ideal solution, but at this stage I am curious if it will
>   actually fix your problem at all. Load this when ever, preferably as
>   soon as possible:
>
> ```
> (function() {
>   var handle;
>   if (!check()) {
>       handle = setInterval(check, 0);
>   }
>   function check() {
>       if ('RTE' in window) {
>           clearInterval(handle);
>           inject();
>       }
>   }
>   function inject() {
>       var backup = RTE.Canvas.checkCurrentFocus;
>       RTE.Canvas.checkCurrentFocus = function(a) {
>           if (a !== null) {
>               return backup.apply(this, arguments);
>           }
>       };
>   }
> })();
> ```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this.  I tried other fixes too.  So, in my master page I have two custom js files in the head just after jQuery is loaded.  One loads normally, the other has `LoadAfterUI="false"` set.  If I put it in the first load, I get `SP is not defined`, and if I put it in the second one, it seems to be too late and the napkin does not *cover* the error.  Should I put it somewhere else or do something different?

Comment: This doesn't solve it for me.  Maybe there's another solution?

Comment: Well, I awarded my bounty to you even though I haven't solved my problem.  Hopefully, you might find the time to assist me a bit further.

Comment: You would need to execute the overriding part the moment the sp.ui.rte.js loads. You can unwrap the code, SP.SOD... wrapper won't work in this case. But you want to use the code inside and make sure that runs right after the original file. Alternatively we would need to wrap it and load it first in such way that we override as soon the object RTE exists. I don't like to suggest a setInterval, but worst case there is no other way. Its hard when I don't have access to your environment. :)

Comment: I updated my original post with some more examples based on your feedback.

Comment: Alex, thanks again; this is a wonderful attempt to solve my error..  I've tried these solutions using various loading procedures and I am never able to resolve the error.  I either get `RTE is not defined` or just the regular error.  I don't know what to do.  I've tried putting it at different locations in the master page, and I've tried using `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push` and `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` and the jquery `document.ready` too.  I'm floundered.